# Problems with adjacency matrix with poly2nb in R

Tags: shapefile, r, spatial-statistics, adjacency, spdep

I am working with a shapefile of Ohio precincts, with the hope of performing areal regression models (probably BYM2). To build the adjacency matrix, I used poly2nb from the spdep package.  As a double-check, I went back and plotted the neighbors for each county. I'm glad I did. In some counties it worked brilliantly, but in others there were numerous missing connections between precincts.

A simple example is illustrated below for Ottawa County. In the northwestern corner, you can see a precinct that lacks any connections, but which obviously borders at least five precincts.  In addition there is a cluster in the south-central area that connects among itself, but not to anything else. To say nothing of the islands.

I don't really know where to start with this, as I have no idea what would cause this.  I can manually add the adjacencies for Ottawa County, but for a larger county like Mahoning or Lucas it would be almost impossible. This is the type of thing for which there might be an obvious list of things to check for debugging/cleaning, but I don't know where to begin.

[image: Plot of Ottawa County Ohio Adjacency Matrix]

Comment: Can you point us to the geodata you used for this? Its probably a badly-digitised set of coordinates, resulting in a tiny gap between polygons. One workaround is to buffer all polygons by a small amount and create adjacencies where polygons overlap..

Comment: You could try increasing the `snap` parameter for `poly2nb`. I've got the data from this geopackage: https://github.com/mggg/ohio-precincts/tree/master/gpkg and I see the same adjacency in this county. Setting snap to `1e-5` seems to fix the adjacencies in the NW at least.

Comment: Hey Spacedman -- yes, that is exactly where I got it from.  I will play around with the snap and see if I can get it to work out.

Comment: st_distance seems to show distance identically equal to zero for two regions which makes me think poly2nb should count them as adjacent. Very odd...

Comment: I think `poly2nb` only counts adjacency if the polygons share two vertices within the snap. A square with a smaller square on top, in the middle of the top side, doesn't get counted because it doesn't share vertices. I might confirm this with author Roger Bivand

Comment: Thanks for this. The advice I got from the big spatial statistics listserv that Bivand runs was to use ArcGIS to remove the slivers. So, I guess that's what we will do!  Thanks for your help here, I appreciate it.